# Unable to ping docker host but the world is reachable

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am able to ping rest of the world but not the host from container in which docker container is running. I am sure someone encountered this issue before

See below details

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64
**Container is using "bridge" network
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a**

IP address for eth0:    135.25.87.162
IP address for eth1:    192.168.122.55
IP address for eth2:    135.21.171.209
IP address for docker0: 172.17.42.1

route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         135.21.248.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
135.21.171.192  *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth2
135.21.248.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
135.25.87.128   *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1


#ping commands from container

# ping google.com
PING google.com (64.233.177.113): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 64.233.177.113: icmp_seq=0 ttl=29 time=51.827 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.177.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=29 time=50.184 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.177.113: icmp_seq=2 ttl=29 time=50.991 ms
^C--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 50.184/51.001/51.827/0.671 ms

# ping 135.25.87.162
PING 135.25.87.162 (135.25.87.162): 56 data bytes
^C--- 135.25.87.162 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
root@9ed17e4c2ee3:/opt/app/tomcat#
```

Comment: Why you are trying to access the host by the external ip? Use container’s gateway IP instead.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/11

Comment: What does the route table for the container look like?

Comment: Just wan to say, the gateway typically trick works, but last time I checked, there's no officially supported method from Docker Inc for connecting directly from a container to its underlying host. If I remember correctly, there are some scenarios where it won't actually work.

Comment: The issue seem to occur in 14.04.2 LTS ubuntu. Seem to work fine in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. The only other difference is docker0 interface has additional gateway configured. I am not sure this is related to Ubuntu version or the additional gateway configuration on docker0 interface

Comment: The issue seem to occur in 14.04.2 LTS ubuntu. Seem to work fine in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. The only other difference is working vm's have docker0 interface has additional gateway configuration. I am not sure this is related to Ubuntu version or the additional gateway configuration on docker0 interface. However if i use host networking option i am able to ping the host without any issues. It appears that something going on with bridge driver on lower ubuntu versions

Comment: Updated the host to 14.04.5 but the issue not resolved. I am going to use the gateway trick as suggested by Swiss